# Turning screen on again after display timeout?

Tags: android

My activity starts with the following code in order to be shown above the keyguard/turn the screen on from standby:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

This works fine, however, the Activity receives another intent after a few seconds (30-45s) and on most devices, the default system display timeout will have already kicked in if the user hasn't touched the device. Is there any way to show the activity again from sleep when the intent comes in? I've tried acquiring a "screen-on"-wakelock when the new intent arrives, but no dice. Thanks!